# Google maps API

Tags: android, google-maps-api, arduino, geocoding

Мы имеем приложение под андроид с подключенными Google maps картой, у нас есть GSM, GPS датчик и микроконтроллер Arduino (хотим сделать отслеживание авто через своё приложение), как реализовать получения местоположения? можно ли реализовать через промежуточный файл(сайт,облако,гугл диск) по схеме датчик -> облако -> приложение ? Какие инструменты использовать для отслеживания по долготе и широте?

Answer (score 0):

Запрашиваете пермишины у пользователя, используете 
[FusedLocationProviderClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient) - который сообщает вам последнюю локацию (широту и долготу). Если надо можете слать эти данные в облако, например [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/). Шлете точку в облако (Firebase) - а на девайсе подписываетесь на обновление данных из облака, при обновлении данных в облаке, данные обновятся на всех девайсах которые подписаны (на эти обновления).

Comment: Как реализовать подписку на обновление данных из облака?использование geolocation api?

Comment: Почитайте про Firebase Realtime Database. Есть куча примеров в интернете от самого гугла, просто подключаете к вашему приложу Firebase и подписываетесь и вам будут заходить данные (которые вы будете сохранять в Firebase отосланные другим устройством) вот ссылка на примеры и объяснения. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-gZAYBMuBs&list=PLGCjwl1RrtcTXrWuRTa59RyRmQ4OedWrt